# Update - App data not getting deleted

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building an ionic hybrid app for Android and iOS, but facing a problem while updating the older version app with the new version.

When I try to update, the iOS update progress indicator is showing as app installing and after I open the updated app, I still see the older version with old data and old views, not getting updated with the new changes. Same happens with Android too.

But, once I clear **data** from **settings > storage**, I am able to see the new changes.

Tried `window.localStorage.clear()` and `localStorage.clear()` which just clears whatever is stored on localStorage.

Not really sure how can I delete the app data from code. Help is much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you uninstall the app and then install it with newer version ?

Comment: If I uninstall the old and install new version, I can see the version in settings > app version as changed to **new version**. But the new changes inside the app are not reflected until I clear app data @Ujjwalkaushik

Comment: @lakshman_dev I am actually having this exact problem with my Android application. When I update the application, it updates to the new version,  however, it still shows the older data. The only way the new data is reflected is if I go into the app settings and hit clear data. Any ideas on how to resolve this in Android?

Comment: Hey Hii, for me The issue is with ionic-m-generator lower version, they have caching issue in their older version. Now I upgraded to newer version of ionic-m-generator, so able to upgrade the app :) @abbanoob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to upgrade the app. The issue is with ionic-m-generator lower version, they have caching issue in their older version. Now I upgraded to newer version of ionic-m-generator, so able to upgrade the app.

Thanks everyone, for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

In each state in the state provider, add a property `cache: false`. For example, do:

```
.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

Comment: That would disable cache. But the problem is not with cache. The problem is with app data.